# Setting up Mongodb on Windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, xampp

I am trying to get starting with Mongodb. I installed it and moved the installation directory to my xampp directory. I would like to start developing using Mongodb, is the `mongod.exe` service required to run, in order to write code that uses mongodb ?

I am able to connect to this service successfully, however once I disconnect from the `mongod.exe` service and try to run `mongo.exe` I get an error saying `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`. I am running `cmd` as administrator. However, when I run the `mongod.exe` service first, then try to run the `mongo.exe`, I am able to connect successfully.

My question is, if I am developing on Windows using xampp, am I supposed to run the `mongod` service prior to writing code to query the DB ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , the mongod.exe(server) needs to be running if you want to read/write data to MongoDB. mongo.exe is a shell which checks if the server(mongod.exe) is running if 'yes' then it allows to read/write data to MongoDB. Hence prior to querying the DB you need to bring up mongod.exe

Comment: Thanks @vmr. Another question, even while running `mongodb.exe` and then running `mongo.exe`, after a successful database insert from the shell, when I go to the `data/db/` folder, no files are created. Doesn't mongo store records as files ? Does this mean something is set up incorrectly on my end ? Thanks for the help!

Comment: data/db should be a top level directory in the same drive. Also check console logs when you start mongod.exe

Comment: It is. However, it is empty after inserts. There aren't any logs, in the mongodb directory.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you leave the default directory mongodb in "C: \ DATA \ DB \ bin" and install mongo as a service to start with windows with the code in CMD:

C:\DATA\DB\bin>mongod --dbpath=C:\DATA\DB\bin\mongod.exe --logpath=D:\mongodb\log.txt --install

configure the service to start automatically and you will not need to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks @Sergio! After a successful database insert from the shell, when I go to the data/db/ folder, no files are created. Doesn't mongo store records as files ? Does this mean something is set up incorrectly on my end ? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, mongodb create files after insert, are you using port 27017 to connect in mongod? Check if the service is running in task manager, if not, search how to install a service of mongodb.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

In this documentation you will find how do this!

If yes, try uninstall and re-install mongodb.